# InvalidRequest in ApiRequestor.php line 108: No such customer: cus_9JHigF9SGUuVJQ

Tags: php, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I just wondering why I got this error:

```
InvalidRequest in ApiRequestor.php line 108:
No such customer: cus_9JHigF9SGUuVJQ
```

in my controller, this is my code:

```
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
use Stripe\Stripe;
...
class BillingController extends Controller
{
    use Billable;
    public function postPayCharges( Request $request )
    {
        $account = \App\Account::find( Auth::user()->account->account_id );
        $plan = \App\Plan::find($account->plan_id);

        $ccToken = $request->input('stripeToken');

        $user = \App\User::find(Auth::user()->user_id);
        $user->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->plan_id)->create($ccToken, [
            'email' => $user->email,
        ]);
```

I am sure that the stripe public key and secrete key I used are valid.
Any idea?

Comment: If Stripe's API reports that the customer ID is unknown then there is _some_ issue with your API key configuration. You should reach out to Stripe support directly: https://support.stripe.com/email.

Answer (score 0):

if your api keys are valid then following can be the issue.

This issues erupts only due to one reason and that is token generated by following function.

Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler)

in stripeResponseHandler(status, response) response.id is the token value. so please use this token to create subscription or whatever... Thanks

Comment: You should consider using formatting, which makes your answer easier to read and understand. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer